# How to delete header name of Json data in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to delete this header "vendor": and { } branch from Json formated output.

The reason to delete is to map these three fields names ("RECORDNO".."NAME") to SQL table.

[image]

Bottom is expected output:

[image]

Bottom is C# code that iterates thru each ones and populates the result, and later uses JsonCovert to format output in Json format.

```
public static string Run(ILogger logger)       
    {
        OnlineClient client = Bootstrap.Client(logger);
        ReadByQuery query = new ReadByQuery()
        {
            ObjectName = "VENDOR",
            PageSize = 600, 
            Fields =
            {
                "RECORDNO",
                "VENDORID",
                "NAME"
            }
        };
        logger.LogInformation("Executing query to Intacct API");
        Task<OnlineResponse> task = client.Execute(query);
        task.Wait();            
        OnlineResponse response = task.Result;
        Result result = response.Results[0];
        LogManager.Flush();
        int i = 1;
        while (result.NumRemaining > 0 && i <= 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ResultId))
            {
            i++;
            ReadMore more = new ReadMore()
            {
                ResultId = result.ResultId
            };
            Task<OnlineResponse> taskMore = client.Execute(more);
            taskMore.Wait();
            OnlineResponse responseMore = taskMore.Result;                
            Result resultMore = responseMore.Results[0];
            dynamic resultJson =   
                   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data));  
            string resultJsonString = resultJson.ToString();  
            return resultJsonString;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I am not fluent in C# so I am not sure how to express to delete the "vendor:" portion from 'query'.

I am sure there are a lot of unnecessary lines from this C# code which could be deleted (to clean up).

What is expression to delete "vendor": and { } branch?

---

This is updated code based on the comment from @Serge.

```
int i = 1;
        while (result.NumRemaining > 0 && i <= 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ResultId))
            {
            i++;
                            
            dynamic resultJson =   
                   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data));  
            string resultJsonString = resultJson.ToString();

            var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(resultJsonString);
            var newJsonArray = jsonArray.SelectTokens("$..VENDOR");
            var result1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJsonArray, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            return result1;

        }
```

When I modified like this way, I got no data output (as shown below).

[ ]

What is proper way (area) to put the bottom code?

```
var jsonArray=JArray.Parse(json);  

var newJsonArray =  jsonArray.SelectTokens("$..VENDOR");
    
var result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJsonArray, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

---

Comment: You can do this very easily in SQL: just use `OPENJSON(@YourJson) WITH (RECORDNO int '$.vendor.RECORDNO', ...`

Comment: Why bother? Just parse it as is and take the info you want from the parsed result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
....

var json="[{\"VENDOR\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"1\",\"VENDORID\":\"ID1\",\"NAME\":\"Name1\"}},{\"VENDOR\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"2\",\"VENDORID\":\"ID2\",\"NAME\":\"Name2\"}},{\"VENDOR\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"3\",\"VENDORID\":\"ID3\",\"NAME\":\"Name3\"}}]"

 var jsonArray=JArray.Parse(json);  

 var newJsonArray =  jsonArray.SelectTokens("$..VENDOR");
        
 var result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJsonArray, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

result

```
  [ {
    "RECORDNO": "1",
    "VENDORID": "ID1",
    "NAME": "Name1"
  },
  {
    "RECORDNO": "2",
    "VENDORID": "ID2",
    "NAME": "Name2"
  },
  {
    "RECORDNO": "3",
    "VENDORID": "ID3",
    "NAME": "Name3"
  } ]
```

or you can create classes and have typed c# list

```
var jsonDeserialized=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VendorRoot[]>(json);

List<VENDOR> newJsonList = jsonDeserialized.Select(d => d.VENDOR ).ToList();

var result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJsonList,  Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

classes

```
public class VendorRoot
{
    public VENDOR VENDOR { get; set; }
}
public class VENDOR
{
    public string RECORDNO { get; set; }
    public string VENDORID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing the codes you have provided, and modified the original post. I am getting no data output. Can you please give me some feedback? Thank you.

Comment: Please see the additional content I provided on the original post.

Comment: @Java All code was tested using Visual Studio and c#. Json is the object that you posted in the white images.  I don' t know how you  are getting it. After  you get json you can use the code that I am suggesting.

Comment: I was able to find the reason. It was due to "vendor" being capitalized ("VENDOR") on the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new JObject assigning to it the JObject value available at the "vendor" field.

You could do something like this:

```
JObject changed =  jobj["vendor"].Value<JObject>();
```

Here is an example:

```
JObject toChange = new JObject();
toChange["vendor"] = new JObject();
toChange["vendor"]["fieldA"] = "value";
toChange["vendor"]["fieldB"] = "value";

JObject changed = toChange["vendor"].Value<JObject>();
Console.WriteLine(toChange.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(changed.ToString());
```

FROM THIS:

```
{
  "vendor": {
    "fieldA": "value",
    "fieldB": "value"
  }
}
```

YOU'D GET THIS:

```
{
  "fieldA": "value",
  "fieldB": "value"
}
```